# Python reflection after module reloading

Tags: python, reflection, module, reload

I am trying to reflect a module after reloading it. Every time I change the module, I need to reflect it to see its current state. The problem is that it remembers all of its previous states. Here is my code.

**main.py**

```
from tkinter import *
from importlib import reload

def fun():
    import second
    reload(second)
    print(dir(second))

root=Tk()
Button(root,text='reload',command=fun).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

**second.py**

```
var1='hello'
```

When I change the variable name in 'second.py' from 'var1' to 'var2' for example, it prints both variables 'var1' and 'var2'.
I need only the latest version of the module (only 'var2').

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`importlib.reload`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.reload) *updates* the module's global namespace, i.e. it retains the old name bindings. If you want a fresh module object, you can remove the old one from [`sys.modules`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.modules) before importing it:

```py
def fun():
    sys.modules.pop('second', None)
    import second
    ...
```

Comment: I tried it, still returning previous variables.

Comment: Did you save the corresponding file? Are you running from within an IDE? Perhaps there's a file caching issue with your IDE.

Comment: I modified 'main.py' as you suggested and saved it, then I ran it. Every time I modify and save 'second.py', I click the button to print. I am using Notepad on Windows, no IDE. Could you please try it to see if it works on your machine.

Comment: @Joseph I misunderstood your question, I thought the new `var2` wasn't showing up. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Many thanks. It works now. I very much appreciate your help.